# How do I reset the thumbnail cache?

Tags: cache, thumbnails

I have a lot of images on my laptop as I work in graphics. On the same system, I also have a folder containing my family pictures.

I would like to do two things:

- Empty the already cached images

and then

- "blacklist" or exclude the folder holding the family pictures as I use Shotwell for organizing/adding/deleting these files

In the settings of Nautilus you can only change global settings.

[image: File Management Preferences preview tab]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Thumbnails are stored in `~/.cache/thumbnails`.  Simply deleting everything in there will reset your thumbnails, causing them to be recreated according to the global settings.  I'm afraid I can't think of a way to prevent a specific directory from being thumbnailed.

**Note**: In Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) and older, the thumbnails are stored in `~/.thumbnails`. But please verify this for your own distro. Lubuntu **12.10** (a clean install) has its thumbnails in ~/.thumbnails and there is no `thumbnails` subfolder in ~/.cache.

Comment: would hidden files or files in a hidden folder be indexed?

Comment: The thumbnailer will only start when you browse to the directory in question - it doesn't silently scan your system looking for things to thumbnail.  So if you have hidden image/video files, they won't be thumbnailed unless you show them.  But if you show them, they'll be thumbnailed!

Comment: looks like a Ubuntu brainstorm/ Launchpad feature request :( thanks for the info though

Answer (score 6):

BleachBit can wipe your thumbnail cache, I believe. Not sure how to blacklist a folder from getting thumbnails, though.

Answer (score 0):

remove thumbnail if the original file does not exist:

```sh
cd ~/.cache/thumbnails
find large normal -type f |
perl -MImage::Magick -MURI::Escape -lne '
    $, = "\t";
    $f = $_;
    $img = Image::Magick->new;
    $img->Read($f);
    $u = $img->Get("%[Thumb::URI]");
    $p = uri_unescape $u;
    $p = substr $p, 7;
    next if -f $p;
    print "rm", $f, $p;
    unlink $f;
'
```