# Is there any command similar to qlmanage in Mac OS?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, macosx

Is `qlmanage` command is present in Ubuntu? Or is there any similar commands?

Comment: Are you asking about Quick Look? If you specify what `qlmanage` does, it will make this easier to answer.

Comment: qlmanage - Displays the Quick Look generated thumbnails (if available) for the specified files in commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Look doesn't exist in Ubuntu, so I'm going to say no to something like `qlmanage`.

There's gloobus, which apparently provides something similar, though I've never used it.

Nautilus (the file manager) has thumbnails, and according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/29529/519) you can reset the cache by deleting `~/.cache/thumbnails` or `~/thumbnails` depending on what version of Ubuntu you're running.