# missing icon after moved partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, caja

yesterday due to no enough space on my `/` root partition I reduced and move right `/home` partition and than I extended the root partition. The actual situation of my SSH is this:

[image]

I did not touch `/media/data` partition.

I did this procedure with a Live of Ubuntu by gparted. All gone well.
Now my system works "good", but I have a big problem:
`.png` and `.pdf` icons are missing
[image]

Furthermore, `caja` (The MATE File Manager) consume a lot of CPU every time I open a folder
[image]
(fan speed goes to the maximum)

This happens in all partition, not only in the `/home` which I moved. Even `/media/data`.

How can I fix? I consume a lot of energy every time I open caja.

Comment: Have you tried [rebuilding your thumbnail cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29526/how-do-i-reset-the-thumbnail-cache)?

Comment: I deleted thumbnail folder`s items. Trying to navigate in folder I still not get icons.

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://askubuntu.com/a/769085/454520

Comment: @pim, tried. Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem!
The reason why I could not see `png`, `pdf` thumbnails was that my `~\.cache\thumbnails` folder had only `root` privileges (I do not know why). After a `sudo chown -R user:user ~\.cache\thumbnails`, my thumbanails started rebuild.

Before changing the ownership:

[image]

After changing the ownership:

[image]

(look at `total` dimension)